# ggplot is randomizing the set of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't get it, let's consider the following datatable :

```
mt=data.table( "index" = 1:10, "matches" = rep(0,10) )
> mt
    index matches
 1:     1       0
 2:     2       0
 3:     3       0
 4:     4       0
 5:     5       0
 6:     6       0
 7:     7       0
 8:     8       0
 9:     9       0
10:    10       0
```

Drawing it with ggplot seems to randomize the data around the true values :

```
ggplot(data = mt, aes(x=index, y=matches)) + geom_jitter() +    scale_x_discrete()
```

[image: data randomization by ggplot]

The ggplot changes every time I redraw it while plot gives the right graph :

```
plot(x=mt$index, y=mt$matches)
```

[image: correct plot]

What is it all about...

Comment: Umm... you're using `geom_jitter()`... why not `geom_point()`?

Comment: "So I added some jitter to my plot. Why is there jitter in my plot"

Comment: If for some reason in the future you want to use geom_jitter and have a replicable plot, set a seed first......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?geom_jitter`

If you want to reproduce the base R plot, the correct way to plot this in ggplot would be with `geom_point` (`geom_jitter` is usually used in cases of overplotting).

```
ggplot(data = mt, aes(x=index, y=matches)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete()
```

[image]